# Create a simple text editor in Android

Tags: android, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I want to create a simple text editor in Android which will open a text file, display the content of that file. The user will be able to cut, copy, paste and then save it. 
Any suggestion or library reference?

Comment: You can use this library https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641368/1770868

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at this [github](https://github.com/paulmach/Text-Edit-for-Android/) project source code.

SUMMARY

Simple notepad app to open, edit and save text files to and from the SD card.

** Some features
-- open email attachments
-- change font size, type and color
-- delete/rename in file browser
-- email as text or attachment
-- Search using "search" button

**Another Project Source Code** . [Android Ted](http://texteditors.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Android_Ted)

You can create new text file, open existing files and of course save them. You can also display line numbers and open recent files. Now you can also search for text inside the openned file.

**Another Project Source Code** - [Qute Text Editor for Android](https://github.com/fbreuer/Qute)